# dpkg: error processing package problem with many errors

Tags: dpkg

```
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php8.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.4-ldap:
 php7.4-ldap depends on php7.4-common (= 1:7.4.30-6+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php7.4-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.4-ldap (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.3-opcache:
 php7.3-opcache depends on php7.3-common (= 7.3.33-6+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php7.3-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.3-opcache (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
o apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                             No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                           mdpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.2-soap:
 php7.2-soap depends on php7.2-common (= 7.2.34-34+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1); however:
  Package php7.2-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package php7.2-soap (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php7.2-common
 php7.2-opcache
 php5.6-common
 php7.2-cli
 php7.2-bcmath
 php7.0-common
 php7.4-common
 php7.0-cli
 php7.4-curl
 php5.6-json
 php7.4-mysql
 php7.2-zip
 php7.4-fpm
 php7.4-bcmath
 php7.2-gd
 php7.4-imap
 php7.4-readline
 php7.4-mbstring
 php7.0-readline
 php7.2-fpm
 php7.2-curl
 php7.4-bz2
 php7.4-cli
 php7.4-intl
 php7.2-bz2
 php7.0-json
 php7.3-common
 php7.2-json
 php7.4
 php7.4-zip
 php7.1-common
 php7.2-mysql
 php7.3-soap
 php7.4-pspell
 php7.2-imap
 php7.1-opcache
 php7.3-mysql
 php5.6-opcache
 php7.2-mbstring
 php7.2-intl
 php7.3-intl
 php7.3-xml
 php8.0-common
 php8.0-ldap
 php5.6-phpdbg
 php7.3-cli
 libapache2-mod-php8.0
 php7.4-ldap
 php7.3-opcache
 php7.2-soap
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Edit your question to add the first three errors in the sequence. The errors at the bottom of the list tend to be least important, subsidiaries of original causes listed near the top.

Comment: I'd like to check your php versions, but I need your Ubuntu data , aka which version of Ubuntu are you using? (Edit your question and don't put it into the comments)

Comment: Use Hestia with 5.6 7.2 7.3 7.4 8.0 8.1 php Ubuntu 20.04